# Write binary file from base64 content

Tags: base64, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have base64 encoded contents (image file) and I'd like to write this to an external file using XSLT/XPath 2.0.

This is my input file

```
<root>
  <img>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAAAAAMAAQMAAACAdIdOAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///
    +l2Z/dAAABpElEQVR42u3OQQ0AMAgEsHOAf7Wbhn0GIa2C5jSLgICAgICAgICAgI
    CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI
    CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgMDgQB6UgICAgICAgICAgICAgI
    CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI
    CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgI
    CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgMDKwB8CAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
    ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
    ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
    ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAu2BC6XQXOr9fnZDAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC</img>
</root>
```

And this my my attempt to write the file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file">

  <xsl:template match="img">
    <myimg>
      <xsl:variable name="filename" select="'hello.png'"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="filename" select="$filename"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="file:write-binary($filename,xs:base64Binary(.))" />
    </myimg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But "nothing happens", which means I get an XML file with myimg as the root tag (expected), but no file written into the current directory. What am I supposed to do?

I use Saxon-PE-9.7.0.15 with oXygen XML

---

Edit: use `hello.png` as a filename (to lessen the confusion)

Comment: Does oXygen indicate any problems with the transformation? Are you sure you want a file name created with `generate-id()`, without any suffix? And are you sure that file is not created? Might be difficult to find. You might want to add an `<xsl:message select="$filename"/>` so that you at least know what to look for.

Comment: @MartinHonnen No problems w/ transformation. Yes, I am sure that I want this filename. Yes, the file is _not_ created. (I do have the filename as an attribute so I know what to look for).

Comment: I am not sure what goes on inside of oXygen, I have tried your code outside of oXygen with Saxon 9.7 EE and it creates the file just fine. You might want to add a tag for oXygen or better try their support forum or email support for faster response. I would first try and absolute file path to test whether that causes the file written where you want it, as there is no error message in oXygen I wonder whether the file ends up being written to some other directory.

Comment: I have now tried your sample again in oXygen and added `<xsl:message select="'current-dir() ', file:current-dir()"/>` to find out which directory it writes to and indeed it had written the binary file in a different directory than the XML input and the XSLT stylesheet are in. So you might want to check that on your side.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That's it! And this was the reason why I didn't find it. It was in  a path that is hidden from spotlight (Mac) so even the 'find everything on my Mac' was unable to find it. If you want, you can put this as an answer, so I can accept this. Thank you very much for the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a problem related to using Saxon and the EXPath file module inside oXygen because when I run the XSLT outside oXygen with Saxon the file is created in the same directory as the XML input and stylesheet code, however inside oXygen the use of `<xsl:message select="'current-dir() ', file:current-dir()"/>` indicates the file module uses a different directory to read from and write to.